# How can I get processor and hard disk manufacturing serial numbers and ids?

Tags: windows, matlab, hardware

How can I get the following hardware attributes using Matlab?

- Motherboard manufacturing serial number
- Processor Id
- Processor manufacturing serial number
- Hard disk Id
- Hard disk manufacturing serial number

And is there any function or class responsible for detecting attributes of other machine hardware components attributes?

I know it can be done using system or console commands, but I don't know how. However, I prefer to know both two ways, the one using Windows console commands, and the one without using it.

Comment: I suggest looking into the implementation of [this tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33155-cpu-info/content/cpuinfo.m)... maybe it can help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a way to get hard disk serial number using console command from matlab:

```
%// Get hard disk serial using windows console command
cmd         = 'wmic diskdrive get SerialNumber';
[~, result] = system(cmd);
%// Extract first hard disk serial number
fields      = textscan( result, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n' );
fields      = strtrim(fields{1});
serialNo    = fields{2};
```

The same for the processor id:

```
%// Get processor id using windows console command
cmd           = 'wmic cpu get ProcessorId';
[~, result]   = system(cmd);    
%// Extract first processor id
fields        = textscan( result, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n' ); 
fields        = strtrim(fields{1});
processorId   = fields{2};
```

It's all about using console command `wmic` + `[hardware name]` + `get` + `[attributename]`
and if you want to know the whole attributes available for some device you can use `get` in your command without naming any attribute, Example:

```
command = 'wmic csproduct get'
```

that will get all available attributes of your machine as a product and its values.

Comment: +1: I hadn't had the time myself to try that, but I had the feeling WMI would be the right direction :)

Comment: Your link was really helpful, thanks a lot, It's you who have solved this question :D.

Comment: Glad to help. Actually it was the maker of that tool who really solved it :) **P.S:** I suggest that you mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: What is the diff. of csproduct identifyongnumber with bios serial number the same always?

Comment: Csproduct UUID will be the same always?

Comment: I don't really recall that because it was a long time ago, but I assume YES as we were using it to generate unique unchangeable code for each machine depending on its hardware components.

Answer (score 2):

I can add some more commands here:

```
cmd='wmic baseboard get serialnumber';
[~, result]   = system(cmd);    
%// Extract first processor id
fields        = textscan( result, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n' ); 
fields        = strtrim(fields{1});
baseboardSN   = fields{2};
```

You can also try the following:

wmic csproduct get name
wmic bios get serialnumber
wmic csproduct get UUID